# How to persist connections during code update in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

When one updates an ASP.NET MVC app in IIS the framework keeps the connections open. All responses to the connections are sent once IIS has caught up. Unfortunately this can take some time (eg. 15 seconds). Is there any way to update part of the app without affecting connections to another part.

An example use case: if you have a web chat app and you want to make a minor change to one section of the website, can it be done without 'pausing' the connections to the chat app.

Answer (score 0):

If you can physically separate the code into its own folder, I.E. (c:/inetpub/wwwroot/myapp and then c:/inetpub/wwwroot/myapp/chatapp), you could define "chatapp" as its own application within the IIS website, and then create a new application pool just for that application. I had to do this before because the project I was running needed to have part of the IIS site on a different recycle schedule due to performance issues, also it crashed a lot so it was advantageous for it to have its own process so it didn't take everything else down with it :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that, or very similar, might be the route that I have to take. I was hoping that the asp.net mvc `Areas` feature might help out here. Did you share session across the two apps (log-in on one and be logged-in on the other)?

Comment: Not in that case, but if you use a session server instead of in-memory session, you should be able to share the session across (not 100% sure though). Unfortunately, Areas in MVC are more of an organizational feature and don't really have an affect on the way the IIS worker process handles requests. The fix to this issue is going to be on the IIS side, not in the actual request code itself.

Comment: Found this article about it:
http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/archive/2011/10/05/sharing-session-state-over-multiple-asp-net-applications-with-asp-net-state-server.aspx

Seems to be hackish to get the session server shared between two or more applications, also you would need to consider which version of IIS you are running and whether the pipelines are integrated or in classic mode.